# Translating a Jar-opening Batch file into its MacOS Equivalent

Tags: java, windows, macos, batch-file

**Hello again** Stack Overflow!

I am currently working on a Java program that is essentially a digitized character sheet for a Dungeons and Dragons style adventure. I'm currently learning how to use IntelliJ IDEA, and while I haven't been able to figure out how to create a standalone executable .jar file, I have been able to find a workaround in the form of a `.bat` file that I have nicknamed `rubberglove.bat` (because if you can't open a jar, you use a...).

However, as in my previous post, I've run into a problem, as one of my new players uses a Mac, and since I don't know if it's possible to run `rubberglove.bat` in a non-Windows environment, I'll probably have to translate it into something MacOS can understand. However, I've never owned a Mac, so I'm not sure what the file extension even is, let alone what to put inside.

The contents of `rubberglove.bat` are shown below:

```
java -jar [program_name].jar
```

What would the Mac equivalent of this file and the commands inside? Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Edited to add the "Hello again" ! Sorry if my question seemed much ruder than it was meant to be ;w;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file called `rubberglove` (or `rubberglove.sh`, the file suffix is optional). And then set the execute bit. Something like

```
$ cat << EOF > rubberglove
#!/usr/bin/env bash

java -jar [program_name].jar
EOF
$ chmod +x rubberglove
$ ./rubberglove
Error: Unable to access jarfile [program_name].jar
```

Adjust "[program_name]" as needed.